# Join tables and keep all rows from main table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

How can you join tables while keeping all rows from the main table?
Specifically using CodeIgniter's database library.

For example, the below code only returns joined rows from `table1` and `table2` where the condition applies for both tables.
How do you return *all* rows from `table1` and only join rows from `table2` where the condition applies?

```
$this->db->join('table2', 'table2.col = table1.col');
$query = $this->db->get('table1');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LEFT JOIN` clause includes all rows from the "left" table (`table1` in this case).

In CodeIgniter this is done by adding it as a third parameter in the `join` method:

```
$this->db->join('table2', 'table2.col = table1.col', 'left');
$query = $this->db->get('table1');
```